# C++: Error in Object-Oriented Program - Works in Visual Studios but not CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I'm new to C++. We are learning object-oriented programming at the moment but I'm having an error with my program. I normally use Visual Studios and the program compiled fine. When I submitted it on Mimir, a program that checks your work automatically, it stated that it did not want to compile. I went ahead to try and run it on CodeBlocks and it does not compile. I'm really stumped with this issue. I'm 99% sure that it is a error within my code and not the compilers.

```
*ClockMan.cpp*
#include "CClockType.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){

    CClockType myclock;
    myclock.printTime();

    myclock.setTime(10,9,35);
    myclock.printTime();

    CClockType yourclock;
    yourclock.setTime(10, 9, 36);
    yourclock.printTime();

    CClockType Figueroaclock (12, 0, 0);
    Figueroaclock.printTime();

    CClockType classClocks[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        classClocks[i].setTime(9,27,30);

    CClockType * ptrClock = & (classClocks[1]);
    ptrClock = &yourclock;
    ptrClock ->setTime(9, 32, 20);

    ptrClock = classClocks;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        ptrClock->setTime(9,27,30);
        ptrClock++;
    }

    int size = 2;
    ptrClock = new CClockType[size];
    CClockType * tmpClock = ptrClock;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        tmpClock->setTime(9,27,30);
        tmpClock++;
    }

    delete [] ptrClock;

    cin.ignore(1124, '\n');
        cin.get();
    return 0;
}

*CClockType.h*
// CClockType header file : class declaration
class CClockType{
    private:
        int hr, mins, sec;

    public :
        //constructor : declare a way to initialize our member variables
        // how to write a constructor (special member function,
        // where the function name is the class name and which syntax is similar to member function but
        // the constructor need no return specifier
        // we can declare diverse constructors
        CClockType();
        CClockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);

        //destructor : special member function which can be used to define how to release all members variables
        //only one destructor is allowed without parameters and with ~ leading the function name
        ~CClockType();

        void setTime(int , int , int ); //member function prototype
        void printTime();
        void getTime(int *hours, int *minutes, int *seconds);
        void incrementTimeBySeconds();
        void incrementTimeByMinutes();
        void incrementTimeByHours();
};

*CClockTypeImpl.cpp*
#include "CClockType.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
void setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
void setTime2(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
void getTime(int *hours, int *minutes, int *seconds);
void incrementTimeBySeconds();
void incrementTimeByMinutes();
void incrementTimeByHours(); */


// TODO Define a constructor with no parameter list
CClockType::CClockType() {
    hr = 0;
    mins = 0;
    sec = 0;
}


// TODO Define a constructor with three int parameters for setting up hours, minutes, and seconds
CClockType::CClockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
    setTime(hr, mins, sec);
}


// Define a destructor
CClockType::~CClockType() {
    setTime(hr, mins, sec);
}

// Define a member function
// (Here we specify the class which function belongs to so that the member function can use all variables and other functions declared in the class )
// static member function is an exception
// TODO Define the member function named setTime, which need three int parameters, hours, minutes, and seconds and return nothing
void CClockType::setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {

    if (0 <= hours && hours < 24) // hours can not be less than 0 nor bigger than 24
        hr = hours; // initialize
    else
        hr = 0;

    if (0 <= minutes && minutes < 60) // minutes can not be less than 0 nor bigger than 60
        mins = minutes; // initialize
    else
        mins = 0;

    if (0 <= seconds && seconds < 60) // seconds can not be less than 0 nor bigger than 60
        sec = seconds; // initialize
    else
        sec = 0;
}


/*
TODO Define member function CClockType::getTime
Goal: read out the hours, minutes, and seconds and save them to the outside variables
Inputs: pointers referring to outside variables used to save hours, minutes, and seconds
Output: void
*/
void CClockType::getTime(int *hours, int *minutes, int *seconds) {

    *hours = hr;
    *minutes = mins;
    *seconds = sec;
}


/*
TODO Define member function CClockType::incrementTimeBySeconds
Goal: to adjust time by increasing seconds by 1.
Inputs:
Output: void
*/
void CClockType::incrementTimeBySeconds() {
    sec++;

    if (sec > 59) {
        sec = 0;
        incrementTimeByMinutes(); // Increment Minute
    }
}



/*
TODO Define member function CClockType::incrementTimeByMinutes
Goal: to adjust time by increasing seconds by 1.
Inputs:
Output: void
*/
void CClockType::incrementTimeByMinutes() {

    mins++;

    if (mins > 59) {
        mins = 0;
        incrementTimeByHours(); // Increment Hour
    }
}



/*
TODO Define member function CClockType::incrementTimeByHours
Goal: to adjust time by increasing seconds by 1.
Inputs:
Output: void
*/
void CClockType::incrementTimeByHours() {

    hr++;

    if (hr > 23)
        hr = 0;
}



/*
TODO Define member function CClockType::printTime
Goal: to adjust time by increasing seconds by 1.
Inputs:
Output: void
*/
void CClockType::printTime() {

    setTime(hr, mins, sec);

    cout << hr << ":";
    cout << mins << ":";
    cout << sec << endl;

}
```

**Error I receive:** 
Compiler/Debug output:

```
g++: error: *.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: error: *.h: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
:g++: error: *.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: error: *.h: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

The correct output of the test case

```
0:0:0
10:9:35
10:9:36
12:0:0
```

Like I mentioned, when I run it in Visual Studios,I get the proper output but when I submit it, it states that it doesn't compile. It doesn't compile in Codeblocks as well. Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: CodeBlocks is not a compiler -- it is an integrated development environment (IDE).  It usually has g++ as the compiler that is used.  So the issue is your setup of CodeBlocks to use g++ correctly.  Second, does your code really contain things like `*ClockMan.cpp*` at the top of the source file?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. No, my code does not contain "ClockMan" at the top. It is the name of the file. I apologize for the confusion

Comment: If you just used g++ from the command-line, you may have more success:  `g++ -o ClockMan ClockMan.cpp`. That is basically what codeblocks is trying to do, but something in the setup is preventing it from running a command similar to that one.

Comment: This is, sadly, what usually happens when one's initial exposure to computer programming and development occurs in a dumbed-down, pointy-clicky, cyber-babysitter that conceals all the fundamental complexity behind pretty dialogs, buttons, and windows. The end result is total unawareness of how the world turns, and what happens at the fundamental level. The compiler is obviously being invoked from the wrong directory, so shell expansion doesn't find any '\*.cpp' files in the current directory, and the invoked compiler then rightfully complains that  "*.cpp: no such file or directory".

Comment: I put your code all in one file (in the right order) and ran it in codeblock, it seems to work fine.